# Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher - is there a way to know in advance whether requested action is dispatchable?

Tags: phalcon

1. I have an ACL controller plugin that's hooking into "beforeDispatch".
2. I have a "dispatch:beforeException" hook that takes care of redirects to error locations when an invalid controller/action is requested.

I need to be able to see in "beforeDispatch" whether the requested action is "dispatchable" (something similar to Zend Framework's `Dipatcher::isDispatchable()` method.

The question:

How can I detect in "beforeDispatch" whether the requested action would fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to use *beforeExecuteRoute* for your application (ACL) instead.

As you can see here: http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events, there is still possibility of stoping operation and throw exception.

Thanks to this approach you will also omit the problem of looping between error page and non-existing routes.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you are correct about moving ACL to *beforeExecuteRoute*. You don't enter it if action cannot be dispatched, thus ACL is not bootstrapped.

Comment: @temuri - check http://cmf.vegas if you want - maybe you will find it usefull for your adventure with phalcon and some problems are already resolved there :)

Comment: Thanks, looks like an interesting project. I guess it's yours? :)

Comment: More or less :) More people are involved :)